# Subversion unexpected 405 on adding file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I've just added a new user to a SVN repository. They have read/write perms on the repo. They also have file perms (up to Modify, including Write and Create) on the Repo directory. When the user tries to add a file to the project, or commit a file, they get a 405 response (note: not a 401).

They seem to be authenticating correctly, but something is out of whack. I'm not much of an SVN admin, so I'm at a loss. Oh, and I've restarted the SVN service. Connecting using Visual SVN and TortoiseSVN through Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, server is Visual SVN Server.

Thoughts?

TIA

CBB

Comment: I found the problem...first of all, it was actually a 403, not a 405. The problem was that the repository name is case-sensitive in Visual SVN, and my path to the repository had some badly cased characters in it.

I was able to fix the casing with the Relocate command, and everything works fine now. It's a Windows (non case-sensitive file system) versus Unix (case-sensitive file system) thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem...first of all, it was actually a 403, not a 405. The problem was that the repository name is case-sensitive in Visual SVN, and my path to the repository had some badly cased characters in it.

I was able to fix the casing with the Relocate command, and everything works fine now. It's a Windows (non case-sensitive file system) versus Unix (case-sensitive file system) thing.